# Laravel Model Query Error : "Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to join 2 tables, but get this error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation**: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `sadaqah_history`.`total`, `sadaqah_history`.`foundation_donate_id` from `dzikir_counter` inner join `sadaqah_history` on `sadaqah_history`.`user_id` = `dzikir_counter`.`user_id` where `user_id` = 25 and DATE_FORMAT(dzikir_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31') in file /var/www/backend/z/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664

### My API Controller code :

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse(new Carbon('first day of this month'))->toDateString();
$endDate = Carbon::parse(new Carbon('last day of this month'))->toDateString();
$models = DzikirCounter::where('user_id', $user->id)
           ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dzikir_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'")
           ->join('sadaqah_history', 'sadaqah_history.user_id', '=', 'dzikir_counter.user_id')
           ->get(['sadaqah_history.total', 'sadaqah_history.foundation_donate_id'])              
           ->actived()
           ->orderBy('dzikir_date', 'desc')
           ->get();
```

### The Model 1 (Dzikir_Counter) :

```
protected $table = 'dzikir_counter';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'counter',
    'dzikir_total',
    'dzikir_date',
    'total',
    'dzikir_detail',
    'status',
    'deleted_at',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by',
];

protected $appends = [
    'dzikir_details'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'dzikir_detail',
    'user_id',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by',
    'deleted_at'
];
protected $casts = [
    'counter' => 'int',
    'dzikir_total' => 'int',
    'status' => 'int',
    'user_id' => 'int'
];
```

### The Model 2 (Sadaqah_History) :

```
    protected $table = 'sadaqah_history';

    protected $fillable = [
         'user_id',
         'name',
         'point_total',
         'total',
         'sadaqah_date',
         'status',
         'is_dzikir',
         'foundation_donate_id',
         'created_at',
         'updated_at',
         'created_by',
         'updated_by',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'point_total',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',        
        'foundation_donate_id',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
         'status' => 'int',
         'is_dzikir' => 'int',
         'point_total' => 'int',
         'total' => 'int',
         'user_id' => 'int',
         'foundation_donate_id' => 'int',
    ];
```

What I want to achieve is **SQL Query** identic to this :

> **SELECT** dzikir_counter.user_id, dzikir_counter.dzikir_date, sadaqah_history.sadaqah_date, dzikir_counter.dzikir_total, sadaqah_history.point_total, sadaqah_history.total, sadaqah_history.foundation_donate_id
>       **FROM** `dzikir_counter` **inner join** `sadaqah_history` **ON** dzikir_counter.user_id = sadaqah_history.user_id AND dzikir_counter.dzikir_date = sadaqah_history.sadaqah_date
>       **ORDER BY** `sadaqah_history`.`foundation_donate_id`  DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`DzikirCounter::where('user_id', $user->id)`

with

`DzikirCounter::where('dzikir_counter.user_id', $user->id)`

The error you get means that the `user_id` column exists in both the `dzikir_counter` and the `sadaqah_history` tables. In that case you should specify which table the WHERE should be executed.