# Displaying liked products from database laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display all liked products of a specific user from the database, but I'm getting an error `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'deleted_at' in where clause is ambiguous` .How can I display all liked products of specific user?

Like.php

```
class Like extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'likeables';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'likeable_id',
    'likeable_type',
];

/**
 * Get all of the products that are assigned this like.
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'likeable');
}

}
```

Product.php

```
   public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'likeable')->whereDeletedAt(null);
}

public function getIsLikedAttribute()
{
    $like = $this->likes()->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();
    return (!is_null($like)) ? true : false;
}
```

User.php

```
public function likedProducts()
{
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'likeable')->whereDeletedAt(null);
}
```

Blade file

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->likedProducts as $product)

<h2>{{ $product->price }}</h2>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926714/laravel-model-query-error-illuminate-database-queryexception-sqlstate23000

Comment: That didn't solve my problem @EyadJaabo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `deleted_at` column  in users table and products table. That's why the error . change your `likedProducts` function like this

```
  public function likedProducts()
    {
       return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'likeable')->whereNull('products.deleted_at');
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Unknown column 'product.deleted_at'` @shihab

Comment: That also says `Unknown column 'user.deleted_at'` @shihab

Comment: @user11710915 do you have any column name with `deleted_at` at any table

Comment: In products table I have `deleted_at` column but in user I don't have `deleted_at` column @shihab

Comment: @user11710915 what is the name of products table is it product or products ?

Comment: It is products table @shihab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201465/discussion-between-shihab-and-user11710915).